# Best way to transfer millions of rows from one database to other

Tags: postgresql, migration

There are two databases: `DatabaseA` and `DatabaseB` with the same schema. These databases have millions of rows.

The plan is to convert them into one single database (`DatabaseCommon`) and multiple schemas (`schemaA` and `schemaB`).

What is the best way to transfer data, indexes, etc. from the existing databases to `DatabaseCommon`?

Is there a Postgres script that can handle this use-case?

We can have downtime. There will be around 20 databases. Users are restricted to their own schema.

Answer (score 3):

First rename the schemas in the current databases to have the names you want to end up with:

```
alter schema public rename to schema_a;
```

And the same for other databases.  Whether you need to change your apps, SQL functions, etc. depends on what kind of coding standards you used in the first place.  This can probably be done with the system online, if your apps can cope and if you juggle search_path appropriately.

Then lock people out of each database in turn, and use `pg_dump` to dump out the schema and data, and load it to the successor database.

```
pg_dump database_a -n schema_a | psql -1 database_common
```

If you have extensions in special schemas, elaborate systems of roles and grants, and stuff like that, then you might need to do some work to get that to work.  There is no substitute for having a test/QA database and using it for testing and practicing.